# command substitution in bash with awk

Tags: linux, bash

Why does this work:

This

```
var=hello
myvar=`echo hello hi | awk "{ if (\\\$1 == \"$var\" ) print \\\$2; }"`
echo $myvar
```

gives

```
hi
```

But this does not?

This

```
var=hello
echo hello hi | awk "{ if (\\\$1 == \"$var\" ) print \\\$2; }"
```

gives

```
awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token
```

I am using

GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

on

Linux 2.6.32-34-generic-pae #77-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 13 21:16:18 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: You can try both the code. You will see and error for second one.

Comment: That's not the way SO works.  A well-formed question includes an explanation of your objective and the results that do not meet your expectations.  People may well try your code, but it is up to you to explain your question completely.

Comment: Ok I edited my question and added the outputs I am getting.

Comment: I get a different error: `backslash not last character on line`. Try `set -x` before and `set +x` after your commands to see a trace of how things work such as variable substitution and backslash evaluation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your awk is like mine, it will tell you where it fails:

```
var=hello
echo hello hi | awk "{ if (\\\$1 == \"$var\" ) print \\\$2; }"

awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    { if >>>  (\ <<< $1 == "hello" ) print \$2; }
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

furthermore, if you replace `awk` by `echo` you'll see clearly why it fails

```
echo hello hi | echo "{ if (\\\$1 == \"$var\" ) print \\\$2; }"
{ if (\$1 == "hello" ) print \$2; }
```

there are extra '\' (backslashes) in the resulting command. This is because you removed the backquotes.
So the solutions is to remove a pair of \'s

```
echo hello hi | awk "{ if (\$1 == \"$var\" ) print \$2; }"
hi
```

Answer (score 11):

The correct way to pass shell variables into an AWK program is to use AWK's variable passing feature instead of trying to embed the shell variable. And by using single quotes, you won't have to do a bunch of unnecessary escaping.

```
echo "hello hi" | awk -v var="$var" '{ if ($1 == var ) print $2; }'
```

Also, you should use `$()` instead of backticks.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. You are right and I am aware of awk -v. But I wanted to understand why did my 2nd attempt actually fail.

Comment: @abc: Getting complex quoting and escaping along with the use of backticks correct is a tricky proposition. Doing it correctly in the first place avoids all that unpleasantness. When I run your first example, I don't get an error, but I don't get any output echoing the variable either.

Comment: Dennis, I added the bash version and Linux version I am using. It works for me just fine. What versions are you using?

Comment: @abc: Sorry, the command substitution does work. In my test, I had `var` set to the wrong value.